# Code Igniter Tutorial Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

When i try to write and run the Code Igniter tutorial, it throws this error:

```
Call to undefined method News_model::get_news() in application\controllers\news.php on line 21
```

Here is *line 21*:

```
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
```

mews model

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this ->db->get('news')
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you defined the get_news method on News_model? is it public?

Comment: Post the `news_model`. Without it we're shooting in the dark

Comment: Once you've called `$this->load->model('news_model')`, it's in the singleton. Any public methods defined within it are available. We really do need to see your model, or at _least_ its constructor if it has one and the definition of the method.

Answer (score 3):

If you use your model in controller - you must write this code

```
$this->load->model('News_model');
$data['news'] = $this->News_model->get_news($slug);
```

And check line

```
parent::__construct();
```

in your controller __construct method.
(PHP does not instantiate the parent constructor automatically if the child defines a constructor, unless the child specifically instantiates the parent's constructor)

If you use model from another side your application you must write this code

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->model('News_model');
$data['news'] = $CI->News_model->get_news($slug);
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining that PHP does not instantiate the parent constructor automatically if the child defines a constructor, unless the child specifically instantiates the parent's constructor (e.g. the 'why' in addition to the 'what').

Answer (score 0):

Without posting more code it looks like there are two things to check here.

First, you have to call the parent constructor in your model. So your News_model constructor should look like this:

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
}
```

Second, if the code for line 21 you posted above is correct, the model name has to match your class name. So line 21 should read:

```
$data['news'] = $this->News_model->get_news($slug);
```

Note the uppercase 'N' in News_model.

This is essential what yAnTar wrote but phrased differently. Hopefully you'll understand either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you

```
1.In your controller:-

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('News_model ');
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

 2.In Model:-
class News_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}
public function get_news($slug)
{
    if ($slug)
    {
        $query = $this ->db->get('news')
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems model not loaded.
You have to load model before using it
Either in controller or in autoload array
In controller load model using

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

And in your case

```
$this->load->model('news_model');
```